# Is it possible to crack the password in this c program?

Tags: c, passwords

Is it possible to print `Password cracked` without entering the string `Password` as input. Is there any memory leak or unexpected behaviour that can set the flag even if entered input is not the `Password`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
  int flag = 0;
  char passwd[10];
  char password[10];

  memset(passwd,0,sizeof(passwd));
  fgets(password, sizeof password, stdin);
  strcpy(passwd, password);

  if(0 == strcmp("Password", passwd)) {
    flag = 1;
  }

  if(flag) {
    printf("\n Password cracked \n");
  }
  else {
    printf("\n Incorrect passwd \n");

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Cracking" this program would be relying on overflowing the buffers, and thus on undefined behaviour.

Comment: So you're asking us an interview question to get you a job? It would benefit you more if you made an attempt and then worked with the interviewer on your problem solving steps. This will get you more brownie points because this tests your teamwork/direction skills. FYI

Comment: @FirebladeDan I never said that I was at the interview .FYI

Comment: Neither did I. Many companies give take home questions. My comment was an attempt to help you. Obviously you know everything.

Comment: I am here to learn. And took your comment as a positive feed back. Just corrected as it was not my interview.

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the compiled binary to change the password? Or using a debugger to change `flag` after strcmp? Or replace strcmp with an implementation of your own with LD_PRELOAD or equivalent?

Comment: @Joni No only by giving the inputs. But if allowed, is it possible how?

Comment: If you have control over the execution of the binary you can do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP has done a significant edit a 2nd time - better to start a new question.  @J.Selva, do not change the question again.

In this version, the below code does not check the return value of `fgets()` (which is an exploit opening)  and yet uses `password`. This creates a problem that may be used to crack.  Say a previous run of code with the correct password occurred.  Now with this run, the nefarious user causes an IO error which `fgets()` returns `NULL`.  The contents of `passwd` are indeterminate and *could* be the value of a previous `fgets()` call.  The `memset()` does not help here as that clears `passwd` and not the internal buffers used by `fgets()` to assign `password`.

```
memset(passwd,0,sizeof(passwd));
fgets(password, sizeof password, stdin);
strcpy(passwd, password);
```

Proper code would use

```
// memset not needed
// memset(passwd,0,sizeof(passwd));

if (fgets(password, sizeof password, stdin) == NULL) {
  Handle_EOForInputError();
  return -1;
}
strcpy(passwd, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Q:  If the input contains 1 to 9 characters, the puts() function works fine. If 10 characters are entered nothing is printed.

   A: That's because you're overwriting your array.  Buffer overrun.  [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
2. *NEVER* use "gets()".  *ALWAYS* use fgets() instead.  For precisely this reason:

   http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1049157810&id=1043284351

Answer (score 0):

Whole thing will depend on overflow of buffers and thus on undefined behaviour.

Comment: Updated Thanks. Bu that was not the point that I was trying you ask.

Answer (score 0):

OP has updated the post replacing `gets()` with `fgets()`.  Now code uses `fgets()` incorrectly and so it can exhibit undefined behavior.

Even if `fgets(password)` replaced with `fgets(password, sizeof password, stdin)` there are still issue of not checking in the result of `fgets()`/

If the user enters `"Password"`, the output is certainly `"\n Incorrect passwd \n"` as `passwd` certainly retains the `'\n'`.

Comment: I get `Password crakced` as output if `"Password"` is entered after editing as you said. [ideone link](http://ideone.com/8ciFQ8)